# Extracting string that only exists in certain rows and is between 2 different delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter

I have the following table and I am trying to extract a string that only exists in certain columns and the string is between two different delimiters (, :).

df:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Patient 001 data retrieved: 9089800, John,Doe | CA |
| Hospital stay | AZ |
| Patient 002 data retrieved: 9123010, Steve,Doe | NY |
| Patient 003 data retrieved: 9034291, Alex,Doe | MI |
| Patient 004 information not found | VT |

df_final

| col1 | col2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patient 001 data retrieved: 9089800, John,Doe | CA | 9089800 |
| Hospital stay | AZ |  |
| Patient 002 data retrieved: 9123010, Steve,Doe | NY | 9123010 |
| Patient 003 data retrieved: 9034291, Alex,Doe | MI | 9034291 |
| Patient 004 information not found | VT |  |

I understand that the way the data is currently is not efficient but this is the dataset/task I have been given. Is there anyway to work around this?

his is what I have so far but it just retrieves the entire string for all rows. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *, 
SUBSTRING(col1,CHARINDEX('data retrieved:',col1)+1,
        (((LEN(col1))-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(col1)))-CHARINDEX('data retrieved:',col1))) AS Result 
FROM df
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you fix your design; that is the real problem here. Then you'll just have a column with the value you need. `col1` looks like it has 4 or 5 different values in it (something like Patient ID, status, some number, forename, and surname).

Comment: I unfortunately have no control over the dataset. Only that they have asked me to extract that specific string for the column. Is there anyway to do that given the current structure of the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit more bullet proof:

```
trim(case when charindex(':', col1) <> 0 then
      case when charindex(',', col1, charindex(':', col1)+1) <> 0 then
          substring(col1, charindex(':', col1)+1, 
              charindex(',', col1, charindex(':', col1)+1) -
              charindex(':', col1) - 1
          ) 
      end
  end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tired of extracting strings ... left, right, patindex, charindex, ...

Here is an option that uses a helper function which accepts two unlike delimeters.  In this case a `:` and `,`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([col1] varchar(50),[col2] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Patient 001 data retrieved: 9089800, John,Doe','CA')
,('Hospital stay','AZ')
,('Patient 002 data retrieved: 9123010, Steve,Doe','NY')
,('Patient 003 data retrieved: 9034291, Alex,Doe','MI')
,('Patient 004 information not found','VT')
 
Select A.* 
      ,Result = B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON](Col1,':',',') B
```

**Results**

[image]

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON] (@String nvarchar(max),@Delim1 nvarchar(100),@Delim2 nvarchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
                  ,RetVal = trim(Value)
             From  OpenJSON( N'["'+replace(string_escape(@String,'json'),@Delim1,'","')+N'"]' )

          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1

)
```

**If you want to try without the TVF  https://dbfiddle.uk/Aw9qByxC**